# React Chrome Extension - Message Exchange between background.js and React Component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am learning React at the moment and wanted to try to build a Chrome extension with it. Unfortunately, I can't get the message exchange to work between my component and the background script. What am I am doing wrong? :)

Here is the code that should exchange information between the background script and the React component:

***** React component *****

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import WatchListEntry from "./WatchListEntry";

const WatchList = () => {
  const [watchListEntries, setWatchListEntries] = useState<any>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
      console.log(message);
      switch (message.type) {
        case "NEW_ARTICLE":
          setWatchListEntries([...watchListEntries, message.article]);
          console.log(message.data);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }),
    [];

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Watchlist</h1>
      <ul>
        {watchListEntries.map((watchListEntry: any) => {
          <WatchListEntry data={watchListEntry} />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default WatchList;
```

***** background.js *****

```
import axios from "axios";

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "watchListMenu",
    title: "Libri Watchlist",
    contexts: ["page", "link"],
  });
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "addToWatchlist",
    parentId: "watchListMenu",
    title: "Test-Funktion-fuer-Links",
    contexts: ["page", "link"],
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === "addToWatchlist") {
    addToWatchlist(info);
  }
});

//Wie kann info für TypeScript verbessert werden? Erst einmal den Typ any gewählt.
const addToWatchlist = async (info: any) => {
  let articleId = getArticleId(info);
  let articleInfos = await getArticleInfos(articleId);
  let { ean, title, authorList } = articleInfos.result.articleAttributeView;
  /*   let ean = titleData.ean;
  let title = titleData.title;
  let author = titleData.authorList; */
  console.log(
    `console.log from addToWatchlist: ${ean}, ${title}, ${authorList}, ${articleId}`
  );
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: "NEW_ARTICLE",
    article: { ean, title, authorList },
  });
};

const getArticleInfos = async (articleId: string) => {
  //Kann die Abfrage immer über chakryotik.buchhandlung.de geschehen? Oder müssen aufgrund unterschiedlicher Bestände die diversen Buchhändler abgefragt werden?
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://...some API call...`
    );
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const getArticleId = (info: any) => {
  let url = info.linkUrl;
  if (url === undefined) {
    url = info.pageUrl;
  }
  let regExpForLink = /article\/\d+/;
  let regExpForArticleId = /\d+/;
  let [match] = url.match(regExpForLink);
  let [articleId] = match.match(regExpForArticleId);
  return articleId;
};
```

***** manifest.json *****

```
{
  "name": "Libri Watchlist",
  "description": "React Chrome Extension für Shopline",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "16": "watchlist.png",
    "48": "watchlist.png",
    "128": "watchlist.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "watchlist.png",
      "48": "watchlist.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["storage", "contextMenus", "https://*/"]
}
```

With the consolo.log in the addToWatchlist function I can see that the information are received correctly. Unfortunately, the message isn't received in my component. Any ideas? :)

Thank you so much for your help!

Stefan

Comment: If React code is in the browser_action (or page_action) popup then it runs only when the popup is shown and doesn't run when not shown. In this case you may want to keep the data in `chrome.storage.local` or `chrome.storage.sync` and simply read it at the start of popup's script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! I don't really understand what browser_action/page_action are doing. But I will try to solve my problem with chrome.storage.local. :)

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry to bother you again! Do I have to make the API call from the content script in this case?

Comment: Sounds like my guess may have been wrong. To avoid that you should always show your manifest.json and explain where each fragment of code runs. To send messages to content scripts you should use chrome.tabs.sendMessage, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Thanks again, @wOxxOm! I just added the manifest.json to my first post. Since I don't get the whole interaction between background, content and the rest it is hard for me to explain the problem. :)